# AnimationDrawable don't work in Android 2.2

Tags: android, drawable, android-animation

I using AnimationDrawable like this:

```
ImageView rocketImage = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.animation);
rocketImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.progress_blue_animation);
rocketAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) rocketImage.getBackground();
rocketAnimation.start();
```

This code work in Android 3.0/4.0/4.1/4.0, but don't work in Android 2.2. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As far as i know, thats a [Bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1818) in 2.1, 2.2

A possible workaround could be:

```
ImageView rocketImage = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.animation);
rocketImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.progress_blue_animation);
rocketAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) rocketImage.getBackground();
rocketImage.post(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        rocketAnimation.start();
    }
});
```

(But i didn't try it in Targets >2.1)

Comment: I want to show an loading animation with using a popup window. Actually it works on 4.0 however dont run on 2.3.3. I tried a lot of things such as using another thread, post method, etc nothing resolved the issue. On 2.3.3 it shows only first image. How could resolve this?

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable？

Answer (score 0):

```
view.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            anim.start();
       }
    });
    view.startAnimation(anim);
```

this works for me.