# Animation Drawable not working in GingerBread

Tags: android, animationdrawable

This question is already been asked,but i didn't find any suitable answers and so I'm posting the question.
I've a `ProgressBar` animation which has multiple images and loads these images like a progressbar. I'm able to run it successfully in 4.0 and higher versions but it doesn't work in 2.3.How to make it work in lower versions?

My Animation Drawable XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/p1_wheel" android:duration="200"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/p2_wheel" android:duration="200"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/p3_wheel" android:duration="200"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/p4_wheel" android:duration="200"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/p5_wheel" android:duration="200"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/p6_wheel" android:duration="200"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/p7_wheel" android:duration="200"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/p8_wheel" android:duration="200"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/p9_wheel" android:duration="200"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/p10_wheel" android:duration="200"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/p11_wheel" android:duration="200"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/p12_wheel" android:duration="200"/>
</animation-list>
```

My XML File

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

My Java File

```
package com.example.progressbarsample;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.DrawableContainer;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ImageView progressbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        progressbar = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        progressbar.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.progressbar);
        final AnimationDrawable frame = (AnimationDrawable) progressbar.getBackground();
        progressbar.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                frame.start();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: what is your minimum SDK version?

Comment: @PiyushGupta Min SDK is 10

Comment: Did you get an Error or only it dont works?

Comment: It doesn't work I don't get any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At Last I found a solution to this.

```
 progressbar = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
 progressbar.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.progressbar);
 final AnimationDrawable frame = (AnimationDrawable)getResources.getDrawable(R.drawable.progressbar);  \\progressbar is the anim.xml file
 progressbar.setBackgroundDrawable(frame);
 progressbar.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                frame.start();
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

try animating after the view is visible like this:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged (bool hasFocus)
{
    super.onWindowFocusChanged (hasFocus);
    //get the animation from your view
    AnimationDrawable explosionAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) mImageView.getBackground();
    //set it visible and start animation
    explosionAnimation.setVisible (true, true);
    explosionAnimation.start ();
}
```

The method **[onWindowFocusChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onWindowFocusChanged%28boolean%29)** from Activity is called after the view is already visible and it gets the focus. So, you will be able to animate your image.
I've tried without **setVisible**  but only a static image was shown. The same happens when I started the animation from onResume, onStart, etc.
The code above works fine for me, including Android 2.3. I'm currently working with mono (with Xamarin), but I hope it's gonna work for you in Java.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with Drawable Animations and it works for me here my Code:

```
mImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.anim);
AnimationDrawable explosionAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) mImageView.getBackground();
explosionAnimation.start();
```

But i think its becausse of the post, try the code without using the progressbar.post

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it works well in 4.0 and greater device but in 2.3 Just the first drawable is displayed animation doesn't work.

Comment: ok then check out this [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11385081/animationdrawable-dont-work-in-android-2-2), that could help you, i hope