# Bitmap animation doesn't work on android 2.3

Tags: android, animation, android-2.3-gingerbread

I get image from server and convert it to bitmap,then set animation for it. It works well on 4.x but in 2.3 it's does't work.

```
imgTopNewsIcon.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

....

```
imgTopNewsIcon.startAnimation(anims);
```

I try to change bitmap to image from drawable then it works. Maybe problem comes from there.

```
imgTopNewsIcon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.app_icon);
```

anyone helps me please

Comment: follow this url:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11385081/animationdrawable-dont-work-in-android-2-2/11385114#11385114

Comment: Thanks, but I want to use image bitmap. Image I get from server can not save to Drawable folder.

Comment: Try using BitmapDrawable else convert bitmap to drawable

Comment: Exactly! Change to BitmapDrawable and use setBackgroundDrawable. Problem's solved. Thanks